# Dynamically generating json property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamic

I have a json object as below:

```
{
    "critiquesAvg": 4.75: , 
    "critiques":[
        {
            'author': 'John Does',
            'comment': "I like it",
            'stars' : 5
        },
        {
            'author': 'Jacob Works',
            'comment': "I like it too",
            'stars' : 4.5
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to calculate the value (4.75) of `critiquesAvg` dynamically by averaging the `stars` property value of the critiques array.

Could somebody help me with it?

**EDIT:**
Apologies, the actually issue I was having was like below:

```
var dealers = [{
    "id", 1874
    "critiquesAvg": 4.75 ,
    "critiques":[
        {
            'author': 'John Does',
            'comment': "I like it",
            'stars' : 5
        },
        {
            'author': 'Jacob Works',
            'comment': "I like it too",
            'stars' : 4.5
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 1345,
    "critiquesAvg": 5 ,
    "critiques":[
        {
            'author': 'John Does',
            'comment': "I like it",
            'stars' : 5
        },
        {
            'author': 'Jacob Works',
            'comment': "I like it too",
            'stars' : 5
        }
    ]
}
];
```

and here I wanted to calculate the values of the `critiquesAvg` property dynamically based on the number of average of the critiques for a particular dealer's data.

Comment: What about redefining property `critiquesAvg` using `Object.defineProperty` function?

Comment: I didn't get what you want, can you give an example?

Comment: @Mritunjay: Just wanted to get the value 4.75 for `critiquesAvg` as `data.critiquesAvg`, having `critiquesAvg` calculated dynamically based on the number of critique objects in the `critiques` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g5q8mqyk/)):

```
var data = {
    "critiquesAvg": 4.75, 
    "critiques":[
        {
            'author': 'John Does',
            'comment': "I like it",
            'stars' : 5
        },
        {
            'author': 'Jacob Works',
            'comment': "I like it too",
            'stars' : 4.5
        }
    ]
};

var sum = data.critiques.reduce(function(x, y) { return x.stars + y.stars });
var average = sum / data.critiques.length;

data.critiquesAvg = average;
```

---

As for the updated question, you need to add an extra loop, for example using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g5q8mqyk/2/)):

```
dealers.forEach(function(data) {
    var sum = data.critiques.reduce(function(x, y) { return x.stars + y.stars });
    var average = sum / data.critiques.length;

    data.critiquesAvg = average;
});
```

Comment: Hello Robby thanks for you reply, I've edited my question a bit, could you please have a look at it again and see if there could be a solution for that? Thank you.

Comment: @JyotiPuri Chrome (yes), Firefox (since 1.5), IE (since 9), Safari (yes), Opera (yes). What browser were you planning on using?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by replacing critiquesAvg by a function like:

```
critiquesAvg: function(){
    var stars = 0;
    for(i=0;i<this.critiques.length;i++) {
        stars +=this.critiques[i].stars;
    }
    return stars/this.critiques.length
},
```

Check script.js this plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dDxkZxKxvq0HRppASnzR?p=preview

Comment: @Jyoti: I've just modified the original question a bit. Could you please have a look at the edited part of it? Thanks.

Comment: This no longer qualifies as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Robby did it, I thought I would extend it to a function

```
function dataGen(data){
    //so we do not overwrite data globally as objects are references
    var data = data;
    var sum = data.critiques.reduce(function(x, y) {
        return x.stars + y.stars 
    });
    var average = sum / data.critiques.length;

    data.critiquesAvg = average;
    return data;
}

var data = { 
    "critiques":[
        {
            'author': 'John Does',
            'comment': "I like it",
            'stars' : 5
        },
        {
            'author': 'Jacob Works',
            'comment': "I like it too",
            'stars' : 4.5
        }
    ]
};

data.critiques.push({
    'author': 'Wacob Works',
    'comment': "I like it too",
    'stars' : 3.5
});

data = dataGen(data);
```

ok great updated to your requirements, hope this helps http://jsbin.com/sevor/1/edit

```
var dealers = [{
  "id": 1874,
    "critiquesAvg": 0 ,
    "critiques":[
        {
            'author': 'John Does',
            'comment': "I like it",
            'stars' : 5
        },
        {
            'author': 'Jacob Works',
            'comment': "I like it too",
            'stars' : 4.5
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 1345,
    "critiquesAvg": 5 ,
    "critiques":[
        {
            'author': 'John Does',
            'comment': "I like it",
            'stars' : 5
        },
        {
            'author': 'Jacob Works',
            'comment': "I like it too",
            'stars' : 5
        }
    ]
}
];

var Dealers = {
    calculate: function(dealer){
        var sum = dealer.critiques.reduce(function(x, y) {
            return x.stars + y.stars; 
        });
        var average = sum / dealer.critiques.length;
        return average;
    },
    gen: function(dealers){
        for(i=0;i<dealers.length;i++){
            dealers[i].critiquesAvg = this.calculate(dealers[i]);
        }

        return dealers;
    }
};

dealers = Dealers.gen(dealers);

dealers.push({
    "id": 1346,
    "critiquesAvg": 0 ,
    "critiques":[
        {
            'author': 'John Does',
            'comment': "I like it",
            'stars' : 5
        },
        {
            'author': 'Jacob Works',
            'comment': "I like it too",
            'stars' : 5
        }
    ]
});

dealers = Dealers.gen(dealers);
console.log(dealers);
```

Comment: Could you have a look at the edited part of the question again and see if there is solution for it? Whe I get the json data of dealers, I want the `critiqueAvg` value to be automatically geneted based on the `critiques` for a particular dealer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a init function to your object ,and do all your calculations inside of it.
if you look at other object oriented languages, usually you do this sort of calculations in your constructor.similarly you can achieve the same with a custom method,which would act as a constructor and will set up the initial **state** of your object.

```
var obj = ({
  "critiquesAvg": 0, //start with zero and init function will calculate the actual avg
  "critiques": [{
    'author': 'John Does',
    'comment': "I like it",
    'stars': 5
  }, {
    'author': 'Jacob Works',
    'comment': "I like it too",
    'stars': 4.5
  }],
  init: function() {
    var result = this.critiques.reduce(function(prev, current, idx, arr) {
      return prev['stars'] + current['stars'];
    });
    this.critiquesAvg = result / this.critiques.length;
    return this;
  }
}).init(); // you are invoking the init method inline here (coding pattern)
           // also watch out for the ( ) around the object literal. 
           // this is what makes the method on the object invokable inline.
```

This is sort of a coding pattern, usually followed to set object states(especially when you  using the object literal syntax in javascript).

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jerexe/1/edit)

**Updated answer**

follows the same pattern, but instead of having a init method for each, a common initialize method would do the same operation.

```
var initialize = function() {
  var result = this.critiques.reduce(function(prev, current, idx, arr) {
    return prev['stars'] + current['stars'];
  });
  this.critiquesAvg = result / this.critiques.length;
  return this;
};

var dealers = [({
  "id": 1874,
  "critiquesAvg": 0,
  "critiques": [{
    'author': 'John Does',
    'comment': "I like it",
    'stars': 5
  }, {
    'author': 'Jacob Works',
    'comment': "I like it too",
    'stars': 4.5
  }],
  init: initialize
}).init(), ({
  "id": 1345,
  "critiquesAvg": 0,
  "critiques": [{
    'author': 'John Does',
    'comment': "I like it",
    'stars': 5
  }, {
    'author': 'Jacob Works',
    'comment': "I like it too",
    'stars': 5
  }],
  init: initialize
}).init()];
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xoqidu/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you for it, really good stuff. Could I ask you to have a look at the edited part of the question again and see if there is a DRY solution for it.

Comment: Thanks BOSS, really clean stuff :)